# stop javascript splitting up variable in html template

Tags: javascript, html-templates

In my javascript file, i have a variable that saves a name.
I also have a html template where i am rendering that name as a value in an input field.
This works fine if the value is one word, but anymore than one, it gets split up.

See screenshot for example. in the example i have a value of 'new house' which is being passed in via javascript. However it has been split up.
When i debug, the name that is being passed through is correct ("new house")
So i'm not sure how to keep it from splitting up

[image]

```html
'<td>',
'<input value=<%= name %>></input>',
'</td>',
```

Comment: Actually, nothing test split up. The DOM you're seeing in the inspector section of your dev tools is an autocorrected DOM, not the actual source you're setting. Use `view-source` to see what you really did (namely, you didn't add quotes, so `new house` becomes `<input value=new house>` and yeah, obviously that results in what you're seeing =)

Comment: ah yeah the quotes were the problem. Thank you

Comment: `'<input value="<%= name %>"></input>'` ???

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to the value of the `value` attribute:

```
'<td>',
'<input value="<%= name %>"></input>',
'</td>',
```